# wrapping bash find command

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I want to write a simple bash script to wrap the default unix/linux find program in bash to find multiple files matched.

Here is my program named `my_find_command`:

```
#!/bin/bash

patt=""
first=true
for i in "$@"; do
  if [ "$first" = true ]; then
    patt="-name '$i'"
    first=false
  else
    patt="${patt} -o -name '$i'"
  fi
done

echo "$patt"
find . -type f \( ${patt} \)
echo 'done'
```

Assume I do have some files that the `find` command would be able to return some files.

But when I call `my_find_command icon.png profile.png` I got nothing.

What went wrong here?.

Comment: Your script runs as expected for me on Linux, but you might want to add a -a to get `find . -type f -a \( $patt \)`  Different implementations of find are finicky....

Comment: You can write your `for` loop more simply as: `for x; do patt="$patt${patt:+ -o }-name '$x'"; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes within strings do **not** work the way you want them to. You are correct that `./my_find_command icon.png` will not find `icon.png`.  But, it will find `'icon.png'`.  For example:

```
$ ls
'icon.png'  my_find_command
$ ./my_find_command my_find_command icon.png 
-name 'my_find_command' -o -name 'icon.png'
./'icon.png'
done
```

The problem comes from trying to put multiple command arguments in a variable.  For a full explanation of the ways that this goes wrong, see   ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).  Instead, use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash    
patt=()
for i in "$@"; do
  if [ "${#patt}" -eq 0 ]; then
      patt=(-name "$i")
  else
      patt+=(-o -name "$i")
  fi
done

echo "${patt[@]}"
find . -type f \( "${patt[@]}" \)
echo 'done'
```

This now prints the correct files:

```
$ ls
'icon.png'  icon.png  my_find_command
$ ./my_find_command my_find_command icon.png 
-name my_find_command -o -name icon.png
./icon.png
./my_find_command
done
```

To demonstrate that wildcards work correctly:

```
$ ls
'icon.png'  icon.png  my_find_command

$ ./my_find_command my_find_command '*icon.png*'
-name my_find_command -o -name *icon.png*
./icon.png
./my_find_command
./'icon.png'
done
```